# Edit content before publishing

Tags: users, nodes

How do I give an authenticate user the permission to edit some contents before publishing it. So currently he has the permission to edit it, but he has to publish it first and then he gets the edit button. I tried going to the edit url which is node/nid/edit, but it didn't work before publishing the content.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe he needs the "View own unpublished content" permission

Comment: He can view unpublished content, but he can either view them or publish them from that page, he can't edit them. But once published, then he can edit them.
I can't him to give permission to edit them before publishing. It works if I give "Edit any content" permission, but I can't give him permission to edit any content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need try this module: [Workflow](http://www.drupal.org/project/workflow)